# NGINX RTMP Record allways on

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I can't make NGINX RTMP module to record the live stream manually, ie, ONLY when I call 
https://mydomain:8080/control/record/start?app=live&name=name&rec=rec or https://mydomain:8080/control/record/stop?app=live&name=name&rec=rec.

The problem is that NGINX always records the stream and I wan't to be able to tell it when to start.

Here's my NGINX config file:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; 
        chunk_size 4000;
        notify_method get;

        application live {

        live on;

        hls on;
        hls_path /hls/;
        hls_fragment 20s;
        hls_playlist_length 60;

        recorder rec {
            record all manual;
            record_path /mp4/;
            record_suffix .flv;
            record_notify on;
        }
    }
}
```

Help, anyone?

Thanks, 
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

I found this when I refered the [source code](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/blob/afd350e0d8b7820d7d2cfc3fa748217153265ce6/ngx_rtmp_record_module.c#L1044). The module always records as long as:

- record is set to `audio`, `video` or `all`
- the record_interval is unset
- there is no file IO execption(???).

I haven't used this module yet, but I think providing `record manual` should do the trick. If that doesn't work I would also try setting the `record_interval`.